# Given a PDF, how to extract the images *and their locations on the page* from the command line?

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line

I have a PDF which includes text and images. I want to extract images from the PDF using the linux command line. I can use `pdfimages` to extract the images, but I also want to find the location on each page where that image is. `pdfimages` can tell me what page each image (from the filename), however that's all it gives me. Is there any other FLOSS tool that can do this?

Comment: No locations part: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf

Answer (score 17):

Well I think the PDF must contain the info for placing them, so this should be possible.  On the other hand a solution can be e.g.:

1. Convert each pdf page to an image with [`pdftoppm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftoppm)
2. Extract the images from each page with [`pdfimages`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfimages)
3. Convert the images to a single 8-bits grey-scale channel (for faster analysis) with [`cvCvtColor`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvCvtColor)
4. Object detection with [`matchTemplate`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_object_detection.html)

Step 1 may look similar to this Step 2:

```
for i in {0..99} ; do pdfimages -f $((i)) -l $((i+1)) file.pdf page$((i)); done
```

Step 3 here* a simple example
In Step 4 you should not have problems with training, because the image will be an exact match.  `matchTemplate( imageToSearch,  pdfPageImg, outputMap, 'CV_TM_SQDIFF')`

(* - link removed as it now appears to be pointing towards a ransomware site)

Answer (score 11):

There's an `-xml` switch for the `pdftohtml` command which will give image position, dimension and source information.

```
pdftohtml -xml file.pdf
```

Comment: Pdfimages and Pdftoppm failed to extract images in my case, your answer worked great and even better with useful information. Thanks, a lot.

Answer (score 6):

There is no guarantee in PDF that if an image is reused it will  not be a separate image. There is very little image metadata in a PDF file beyond the page location and its actual size on the page. I wrote an article explaining how images are stored inside a PDF at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-images/

Comment: So is there an easy to use command/library for extracting that page location?